# Distance to a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let E be the set of real sequences $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ such that the series $\sum u_{n}^2$ converges.

For $x=(x_n)_{n \in N} $and $y=(y_n)_{n \in N}$

Inner product :

(x|y) = $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x_ny_n$

Let F be the vector subspace of E formed from zero sequences starting from a certain rank.

If $ z=(\frac{1}{n+1})_{n\in N} $, show that $z \in E $and calculate $d(z,F)$

Showing that $z\in E$ is easy with Riemann. I tried to find an orthogonal base of F to calculate $d(z,F)$ but I couldn’t find one. Is there another way to do the calculus of a distance without using  an orthogonal projection? Here the spaces considered have infinite dimension so there has to be another way !

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I am struggling with Latex as I am new to it and i still don’t know how to make a proper sum and can’t find help anywhere to achieve it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Should I repost my question as it had been downvoted ?

Comment: To what kind of Riemann theorem are you referring to?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net there was a mistake in what i wrote. It should be clearer now

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The given space $E$ is the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$. The space $F$ of eventually vanishing sequences is usually denoted by $c_{00}$.

$c_{00}$ is dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$. This is quite easy to prove. Hence $d(x,F)=0$ for any $x \in E$.

Comment: Could you give a hint to prove that $c_{00}$ is dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: Look at the distance between an element $x \in E$ and the same element with zeros starting at rank $n$.

Comment: For such a sequence of elements of $c00$, the distance intuitively tends to 0, thus proving that $x$ is adherent to $c00$ and that $c00$ is dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$. I just don’t know how to formulate clearly with the inner product that is given

Comment: Is it correct to say that a following of followings tends to another following ? So that the distance tends to 0?

Comment: Just write what the distance is between the two elements I mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: I don’t know how to write it.

Comment: Come on! Just try to use the definition of the distance using the inner product.